# Using external parquet tables in a DBT pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, hive, parquet, dbt

I'm trying to set up a simple DBT pipeline that uses a parquet tables stored on Azure Data Lake Storage and creates another tables that is also going to be stored in the same location.

Under my `models/` (which is defined as my sources path) I have 2 files `datalake.yml` and `orders.sql`. `datalake.yml` looks like this:

```
version:2
sources:
   - name: datalake
     tables:
        - name: customers
          external:
             location: path/to/storage1 # I got this by from file properties in Azure
             file_format: parquet
          columns:
             - name: id
               data_type: int
               description: "ID"
             - name: ...
```

My `orders.sql` table looks like this:

```
{{config(materialized='table', file_format='parquet', location_root='path/to/storage2')}}
select name, age from {{ source('datalake', 'customers') }}
```

I'm also using the `dbt-external-tables` package. Also note that when I run `dbt debug` everything is fine and I can connect to my database (which happens to be Databricks).

I tried running `dbt run-operation stage_external_sources` which returns `Error: staging external sources is not implemented for the default adapter`. When I run `dbt run`, I get `Error: UnresolvedRelation datalake.customers`.

Or perhaps I could make use of the hive metastore instead somehow? Any tips on how I could fix this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I help maintain both the `dbt-spark` plugin and the `dbt-external-tables` package. I can confirm that their interoperability is still preliminary, and I'd *strongly* welcome contributions to improve it. I don't think it's a big lift, though one of the challenges is the fact that Spark/Databricks supports two different `create external table` syntaxes (as noted in [that issue](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-external-tables/issues/10)).

FWIW I see that you specified `path/to/storage` as the external location of your source *and* the `location_root` config of your `orders` model. The former is the place to read data *from*, and the latter is the place to materialize the model as a table. I wasn't sure if you meant that to represent the same placeholder or different ones.

**Edit:** TIL that you can select from some file types directly in SparkSQL as `select * from filetype.filepath`. I believe you could register a source like:

```
version:2
sources:
 - name: datalake
   schema: parquet
   tables:
     - name: customers
       identifier: "path/to/storage1"
       quoting:
         identifier: true
```

This means you could have templated code like:

```
select * from {{ source('datalake', 'customers') }}
```

Which will resolve to:

```
select * from parquet.`path/to/storage1`
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, Jeremy, I really appreciate it. I updated my original question to reflect that `path/to/storage` in source and destination are different locations. I still consider myself to be a beginner with respect to DBT, but I love this tool and I will see if I (or my team) can contribute here.

Comment: One more question: in the absence of an appropriate solution, are there any disadvantages to registering external tables as views with `select a,b from parquet.'path/to/file'` without using `{{ref()}}`?

Comment: No real downside to that approach! I didn't know you could select from parquet files directly based on their path in SparkSQL. That's... really cool. I'll edit my answer above to include an approach that still leverages sources.

Comment: Awesome! Well, that means that the problem is indeed solved :)

Comment: @JeremyCohen is there a way to use freshness reporting using this approach? Cause the errorr i'm getting is that its unable to find the view/table hive_metastore.parquet.{path}.

Answer (score 1):

This might not yet be available. Looks like it's still an open issue with no dev work so far.

Related issue for `dbt-external-tables` package repo: [Support Spark external tables](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-external-tables/issues/10)

Do you have the dependencies from `dbt-spark` installed?

Here are some relevant issues there:

[Spark_connection_url do not contain workspace_id while connecting to databricks](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-spark/issues/29)

[Support Delta Lake format](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-spark/issues/30)

I realize those aren't exactly help with the easy `dbt-external-tables` use-case but it looks like development is still on-going to support the azure databricks / datalake stack.

Gonna try to dig into this a bit more later because this is a use-case that's relevant to me also.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts! My plan B is to create views for my external tables as `select a,b from parquet.`path/to/file`` which works, but isn't ideal. I was hoping that I could define these external dependencies in a yaml, but as you said, it might still be in the backlog.